# ssh asking for password when trying to login via public key

Tags: ssh, key-authentication

Although these lines are present in my server's `/etc/ssh/ssd_config`

```
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
```

when trying to login to the above server by explicitly providing a private key to use for authentication, I am prompted for a password:

```
$ ssh -i ~/Desktop/some_id_rsa myusername@server-hostname
myusername@server-hostname's password:
```

Comment: Is your public key referenced in the authorized public keys on the server in `.ssh/authorized_keys` ?

Comment: yes it has been added in `/home/myusername/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Comment: Look at the output of `ssh -vvv ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kindly change the permission of `authorized_keys`

```
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to delete all the keys and backup your `authorized_keys` and follow this steps:

#### 1. Create key in the client:

```bash
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096
```

#### 2. Copy the public Key to the remote device

##### 2.A. Using `ssh-copy-id` (best option)

```bash
ssh-copy-id <user>@<remote-host>
```

##### 2.B. Using Secure Copy (recommended for remote CentOS hosts)

- **B.1.** First, set up an SSH connection with the remote user:

```bash
ssh <user>@<remote-host> -p <port>
```

- **B.2.** Next, create the `~/.ssh` directory as well as the `authorized_keys` file:

```bash
mkdir -vp ~/.ssh
touch ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

- **B.3.** Use the `chmod` command to change the file permission:

```bash
sudo chmod -v 700 ~/.ssh
sudo chmod -v 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

- **B.4.** Copy the content from `id_rsa.pub` (the SSH public key) to the previously created `authorized_keys` file on the remote server by typing the command:

```bash
scp ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub -P <port> <user>@<remote-host>:~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

#### Note:

Verify is your directories `$HOME`, `.ssh` and the file `authorized_keys` have the correct permission in the client:

```bash
sudo chmod -v 700 ~
sudo chmod -v 700 ~/.ssh
sudo chmod -v 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

- `chmod 700` makes the file executable
- `chmod 600` allows the user to read and write the file.

Comment: There must be no space after remote host and the double colon/path. `<user>@<remote-host>:~/.ssh/authorized_keys` worked for me, `scp ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub -P <port> <user>@<remote-host> :~/.ssh/authorized_keys` didn't.